# Elements isn't spawning when function called out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, pug

I have a classic calculator and converter.

I have two buttons for converter:

- first converter button spawns converter,
- second toggles it.

I was trying to make it work with 1 button (calc-classic) and it isn't working.

At the moment it spawns the calculator but it doesn't toggle.

If I modify it will start spawning empty 1 mm big div.

Part in jade file

```
li
  a(onclick="toggleElement('calc-menu', this)").calculator
    i.fa.fa-calculator
      ul.calc-menu#calc-menu(style="display:none")
        li
          a(data-type="classic", onclick="toggleElement('classic','calc-classic', this)" ).calc-classic
            i(class="fa fa-calculator")
        li
          a(data-title="Konvertetajs", data-type="converter")
             i(class="fa fa-exchange")
        li
          a(onclick="toggleElement('calc-converter', this)" ).calc-converter
             i(class="fa fa-exchange")
        li
          a(data-title="Molje", data-type="molje")
             i(class="icon-vent")
 li
    a(onclick="toggleElement('notes', this)").notes
        i.fa.fa-sticky-note
```

js part

```
function toggleElement(element, $this) {
  if($.inArray(element, ["libraries", "calc-menu", "notes", "calc-converter", "calc-classic"]) !== -1 ) {
    $($this).toggleClass('active');
  }

  if($.inArray(element, ["calculator", "notes", "calc-converter", "calc-classic"]) !== -1 ) {
    $("html").css('cursor', '');
  }

  if(element.indexOf("level") == 0 || element.indexOf("level") == 5){
    $("#"+element).closest("li").find("a").find("i").first().toggleClass("fa-folder-open");
  }
  $("#"+element).toggle();
}
```

Comment: Can you reframe your first sentence? Can't understand much about your issue. Specifically - "1 spawns it sec toggles it and I don't know why."